# Can we add extra rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
     
data = {'id':[22.5, 24.5, 25.5],
        'id_value':[100, 110, 120],
        'new': [100, 110, 120]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

import numpy as np
Range = pd.DataFrame(data = np.arange(21, 30), columns=['id'])
df = pd.merge(df, Range, on =["id"], how ="outer")
```

can I add extra entries in "id"? without the last three line of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try `append`:

```
>>> df.append(pd.DataFrame(range(21, 30), columns=['id']))

     id  id_value    new
0  22.5     100.0  100.0
1  24.5     110.0  110.0
2  25.5     120.0  120.0
0  21.0       NaN    NaN
1  22.0       NaN    NaN
2  23.0       NaN    NaN
3  24.0       NaN    NaN
4  25.0       NaN    NaN
5  26.0       NaN    NaN
6  27.0       NaN    NaN
7  28.0       NaN    NaN
8  29.0       NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas-dataframe-append)

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame({"id":np.arange(21, 30)}), ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
      id  id_value    new
0   22.5     100.0  100.0
1   24.5     110.0  110.0
2   25.5     120.0  120.0
3   21.0       NaN    NaN
4   22.0       NaN    NaN
5   23.0       NaN    NaN
6   24.0       NaN    NaN
7   25.0       NaN    NaN
8   26.0       NaN    NaN
9   27.0       NaN    NaN
10  28.0       NaN    NaN
11  29.0       NaN    NaN
```